# Radial reveal of image in OpenGL shader

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, fragment-shader

I'm playing with a shader concept to radially reveal an image using a shader in OpenGL ES. The end goal is to create a circular progress bar by discarding fragments in a fragment shader that renders a full circular progress texture.

I have coded my idea [here in ShaderToy](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/XlsSDN) so you can play with it. I can't seem to get it to work, and since there's no way to debug I'm having a hard time figuring out why.

Here's my glsl code for the fragment shader:

```
float magnitude(vec2 vec)
{
    return sqrt((vec.x * vec.x) + (vec.y * vec.y));
}

float angleBetween(vec2 v1, vec2 v2)
{
    return acos(dot(v1, v2) / (magnitude(v1) * magnitude(v2)));
}

float getTargetAngle() 
{
    return clamp(iGlobalTime, 0.0, 360.0);
}

// OpenGL uses upper left as origin by default
bool shouldDrawFragment(vec2 fragCoord)
{
    float targetAngle = getTargetAngle();

    float centerX = iResolution.x / 2.0;
    float centerY = iResolution.y / 2.0;
    vec2 center = vec2(centerX, centerY);

    vec2 up = vec2(centerX, 0.0) - center;
    vec2 v2 = fragCoord - center;

    float angleBetween = angleBetween(up, v2);

    return (angleBetween >= 0.0) && (angleBetween <= targetAngle);
}

void mainImage( out vec4 fragColor, in vec2 fragCoord )
{
  vec2 uv = fragCoord.xy / iResolution.xy;
  if (shouldDrawFragment(fragCoord)) {
    fragColor = texture2D(iChannel0, vec2(uv.x, -uv.y));
  } else {
    fragColor = texture2D(iChannel1, vec2(uv.x, -uv.y));
  }
}
```

It sweeps out revealing from the bottom on both sides. I just want it to sweep out from a vector pointing straight up, and moving in a clockwise motion.

Comment: It looks fine. is it for Android or IOS? Either one has a debug tool.

Comment: It's not fine, hence my question here. I have code running on shader toy. Platform doesn't matter, it's a general shader question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code:

```
const float PI     = 3.1415926;
const float TWO_PI = 6.2831852;

float magnitude(vec2 vec)
{
    return sqrt((vec.x * vec.x) + (vec.y * vec.y));
}

float angleBetween(vec2 v1, vec2 v2)
{
    return atan( v1.x - v2.x, v1.y - v2.y ) + PI;
}

float getTargetAngle() 
{
    return clamp( iGlobalTime, 0.0, TWO_PI );
}

// OpenGL uses upper left as origin by default
bool shouldDrawFragment(vec2 fragCoord)
{
    float targetAngle = getTargetAngle();

    float centerX = iResolution.x / 2.0;
    float centerY = iResolution.y / 2.0;
    vec2 center = vec2(centerX, centerY);

    float a = angleBetween(center, fragCoord );

    return a <= targetAngle;
}

void mainImage( out vec4 fragColor, in vec2 fragCoord )
{
  vec2 uv = fragCoord.xy / iResolution.xy;
  if (shouldDrawFragment(fragCoord)) {
    fragColor = texture2D(iChannel0, vec2(uv.x, -uv.y));
  } else {
    fragColor = texture2D(iChannel1, vec2(uv.x, -uv.y));
  }
}
```

**Explanation:**

The main change I made was the way the angle between two vectors is calculated:

```
return atan( v1.x - v2.x, v1.y - v2.y ) + PI;
```

This is the angle of the difference vector between v1 and v2. If you swap the x and y values it will change the direction of where the 0 angle is, i.e. if you try this:

```
return atan( v1.y - v2.y, v1.x - v2.x ) + PI;
```

the circle begins from the right rather than upwards. You can also invert the value of atan to change the direction of the animation.

You also don't need to worry about the up vector when calculating the angle between, notice the code just takes the angle between the center and the current frag co-ordinates:

```
float a = angleBetween(center, fragCoord );
```

**Other Notes:**

Remember calculations are in radians, not degrees so I changed the clamp on time (although this doesn't really affect the output):

```
return clamp( iGlobalTime, 0.0, TWO_PI );
```

You have a variable with the same name as one of your functions:

```
float angleBetween = angleBetween(up, v2);
```

which should be avoided since not all implementations are happy with this, I   couldn't compile your shader on my current machine until I changed this.

Comment: This works exactly how I wanted it to. Updated my saved shader on ShaderToy. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change only two functions below

```
float getTargetAngle() 
{
    return clamp(iGlobalTime, 0.0, 6.14);
}

bool shouldDrawFragment(vec2 fragCoord)
{
    float targetAngle = getTargetAngle();

    float centerX = iResolution.x / 2.0;
    float centerY = iResolution.y / 2.0;
    vec2 center = vec2(centerX, centerY);

    vec2 up = vec2(centerX, 0.0) - center;
    vec2 v2 = fragCoord - center;


  if(fragCoord.x>320.0)// a half width
  {
    up += 2.0*vec2(up.x,-up.y);
    targetAngle *= 2.;
  }
  else  
  {
    up -= 2.0*vec2(up.x,-up.y);
    targetAngle -= 1.57;
  }
    float angleBetween = angleBetween(up, v2);

    return (angleBetween >= 0.0) && (angleBetween <= targetAngle);
}
```